# How to install Sphinx Search (2.0.6) on Mamp using OS X (10.8.x) Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, installation, sphinx, mamp

I'm trying to install Sphinx Search on Mamp but I can't get past a certain step. Here's what I did:

1. Downloaded MAMP (use it to test website locally)
2. Downloaded and unpacked Sphinx Search 2.0.6 tar file
3. Typed "./configure" and I get the following error:

> ### configuring Sphinx
>
> checking for CFLAGS needed for pthreads... none checking for LIBS
>   needed for pthreads... -lpthread checking for pthreads... found
>   checking for pthread_mutex_timedlock... no checking whether to compile
>   with MySQL support... yes checking for mysql_config... mysql_config
>   checking for mysql_real_connect... no checking for
>   mysql_real_connect... no checking MySQL include files... configure:
>   error: missing include files.
>
> *****************************************  ERROR: cannot find MySQL include files.

And then I tried the answer from here: [Sphinx 2.0.4 Install Error with MAMP 2.0: Can't Find MySQL Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569877/sphinx-2-0-4-install-error-with-mamp-2-0-cant-find-mysql-headers) but I can't find the following mysql header files or directory: /Applications/MAMP/Library/include/mysql. Maybe because I'm using the new MAMP version.

Has anyone tried doing this recently? Any help would be highly appreciated. I'm so lost.

Answer (score 2):

MAMP is missing some mysql's library and include files that sphinx requires. You have to upgrade your MAMP by coping the required files to the `MAMP/Library/` directory.

1. Go to your `MAMP/Library` directory and create mysql directory:
2. Go to http://downloads.mysql.com/archives.php and download the appropriated one. You could go to phpMyAdmin to check your MAMP's mysql version.
3. Untar it and copy the `include/` and `lib/` to the `MAMP/Library/mysql` you just created before.
4. In terminal, assuming your MAMP is located in `/Applications/`, then your configure should be like below:

   $ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/sphinx --with-mysql-includes=/Applications/MAMP/Library/mysql/include --with-mysql-libs=/Applications/MAMP/Library/mysql/lib

I hope this helps. You can check out [this blog](http://quyennt.com/sphinx-open-source-fulltext-search-engine/) on this problem.